# How to access the previous value of a series with Security function

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to plot an indicator on pinescript for which I need to calculate EMA of two series of data.

The security function doesn't return the series as the timeframe of the higher chart it divides them into the timeframe of the lower chart.

```
study("My Script")
s5v = 12
ul = sma( high * (1 + 4 * (high - low) / (high + low)), length = 14)
s5r = 26
s5g = 9
vc1 = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", ema(close, s5v)) - security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", ema(close, s5r))
plot(vc1)
```

is there any way i can get the series of data in higher timeframe terms?

I need it in such a way because while referring to the previous value in return series it points to the divided value, not the previous value in the higher timeframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses only one security call to fetch your `vc1` value from the higher TF, and then it uses another one to get the previous value from the HTF also:

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")
s5v = 12
ul = sma( high * (1 + 4 * (high - low) / (high + low)), length = 14)
s5r = 26
s5g = 9
maDiff = ema(close, s5v) - ema(close, s5r)
vc1 = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", maDiff)
plot(vc1, "vc1")

// Fetch previous value from higher TF.
vc1Previous = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", maDiff[1])
plot(vc1Previous, "vc1Previous", color.blue, transp = 60)
```

[image]